# Add # in the end of the url

Tags: symfony

I need add #produc to my url. It must lokoks loke trololo.com/buy#apple. How i can do it in my controller? I can't understand where i must add it...
I read it https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3910, but it don't help me. This not exacly what i need

```
$this->get('router')->generate('store', array('#' => $product->getSlug(), true),
```

Maybe someone faced with it? Please, help me to solved this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your answer in [the link you provided](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3910). Fabien Potencier (Symfony2's creator) said that you need to append the anchor to the URL manually.

> There is no need to that. Just append it after generating the URL.

Like so:

```
$url = $this->get('router')->generate('store') . '#' . $product->getSlug();
```